# How to pass null value to Document Literal SOAP Request

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

Hi,
I am passing the null value for the resourcekey in the SOAP Request as below.

```
 <urn:createNetwork>
 <net:resourceIdentityInfo>
        <api:resourceKey ></api:resourceKey>
           <api:resourceName>TEST2</api:resourceName>
           <api:resourceType>NETWORK</api:resourceType>
 </net:resourceIdentityInfo>
 </urn:createNetwork>
```

The sample WSDL file for this request is as below:

```
 <wsdl:operation name="createNetwork">

     <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

     <wsdl:input name="createNetworkRequest">

        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

     </wsdl:input>

     <wsdl:output name="createNetworkResponse">

        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

     </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

  <element name="createNetwork">
 <complexType>
 <sequence>
  <element name="in0" type="tns5:NetworkInfo"/>
 </sequence>
</complexType>
 </element>
 <element name="createNetworkResponse">
 <complexType>
 <sequence>
  <element name="createNetworkReturn" type="tns2:ResourceIdentityInfo"/>
 </sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<wsdl:message name="createNetworkRequest">
  <wsdl:part element="intf:createNetwork" name="parameters">
  </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
 <complexType name="NetworkInfo">
<sequence>
 <element name="comments" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"/>
 <element name="description" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
 <element name="dnsDomainName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
 <element name="documentUrls" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"/>
 <element name="resourceIdentityInfo" nillable="true" type="tns2:ResourceIdentityInfo"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="ResourceIdentityInfo">
<sequence>
 <element name="resourceKey"  nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
 <element name="resourceName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
 <element name="resourceType" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
```

I have declared as nillable=true in all the places. 
If i pass the resourcekey as empty, in SOAP UI I am getting null pointer exception.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
     <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
     <faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ns1:hostname   xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">linbgg244.lss.emc.com</ns1:hostname>
     </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tried with

```
<api:resourceKey xsi:nil="true" ></api:resourceKey>
```

The same null pointer exception is getting.

Could you please guide to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of where exactly you are getting the error in soapUI? which version of soapUI are you using, pro or OS version? I am guessing that you have the latest patch of java applied. Have a look at http://forum.loadui.org/viewtopic.php?t=8154

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I am getting error when I invoke the SOAP operation createNetwork. My requirement is I do not need to pass the resourcekey value. so passing null/empty to it. If i pass the same in RPC/Encoded WSDL, it worked. Only with Doc/Literal did not work. I am using SOAP UI 4.5.2

Comment: have you tried not passing that element all together? have you tried just right clicking on the request xml in soapUI and selecting validate?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to pass `null` here. AFAIK, the webservice code is throwing the `NullPointerException` during processing of the `SOAP` request. Try to identify why is that ? and do a `null` check or make changes in the logic to prevent it.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. I am facing issue with document/literal WSDL format only. When I use a different RPC/Encoded WSDL format, there is no issue.     <resourceIdentityInfo xsi:type="api:ResourceIdentityInfo" xmlns:api="http://api.common.configmgr.powerup.com">
               <resourceKey xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"></resourceKey>
               <resourceName xsi:type="xsd:string">TEST</resourceName>
               <resourceType xsi:type="xsd:string">NETWORK</resourceType>
            </resourceIdentityInfo>

Comment: Here I am passing xsi:nil="true" option. It gives me the response properly in another server. During document/literal WSDL Format, the request did not reach the SOAP host, it throws the error Null pointer exception.

Comment: Octopus is correct, the response XML you have in your question is coming back from your webservice, so it is the web service that is returning this response. As this same service is working correctly through another client i would recommend you compare the raw XML from both the clients and see how they are different, look at the headers too.